# How to store my game data (global state) on iOS to avoid corruption?

Tags: ios

I'm making a game and I need to store many values between game launches - amount of currency player earned, what he has unlocked and many other things.

The route I chosen is serializing my data and storing it on disk.

So I save my state in

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

method, and restore it every time my game starts. I serialize data by implementing the methods:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
```

I have few questions with this approach:

1. I use atomic writing to disk with this method:

   [data writeToFile:docPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

As I understand this more or less guarantees that my data will not stop writing midway and become corrupt? Does this save me from when the game crashes during save?

1. If my data corrupts, how do I detect this, is this even possible and how do I gracefully restore?
2. Maybe there is another way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: i think may be better to use CoreData

Comment: @stosha I don't have massive amount of data to store, I think adding core data is a bit of overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when your app crashes, the OS will kill all active threads. If a write was in progress when that happens, then the write will be corrupted.

NSDataWritingAtomic will not guarantee that the write happens successfully, only that you won't see a corrupted, partially-written file on disk. One common pattern is to write to a temporary save file, then (after that was successful) delete the old save file, then (after that was successful) rename the temporary file. Internally, NSDataWritingAtomic does something similar: it writes your data to a temporary file first and then exchanges the temp with the target.

That said, keeping old save files around *can* be useful. You can use a naming scheme that lets you leave old save files on disk, whether that's one or ten or a billion.

> If my data corrupts, how do I detect this, is this even possible and
>   how do I gracefully restore?

You won't know that the data was corrupted. Chances are the app was just killed and you're left with no indication that the previous session even happened. That's why you need a strategy in place such that a failed write doesn't permanently destroy useful information, such as leaving an old save file in place.

> Maybe there is another way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

As mentioned above. Or: CoreData. Or: saving data to preferences.